# How to kepp placeholder text when we create duplicate of the elements with .clone() by using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for how to keep the data placed in ***placeholder*** when a new line is added. Indeed, when adding a new line, it duplicates the data of the previous line.
But I would like to retrieve the placeholder values ​​instead of the data entered by the user.
Any ideas ?

Here is the script :

```js
$('#add_address').click(function(event) {
  var lastDiv = $('#address > div').last();
  var id = parseInt(lastDiv.attr("id")) + 1;
  (lastDiv.clone(true).attr("placeholder", name)).insertAfter(lastDiv).find(".removeclass").show();
  return false;
});

$('body').on('click', '.removeclass', function(event) {
  $(this).parent().remove();
  return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="test5.php" method="post">
  <div style="margin-bottom:5px;">
    <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="First name" />
    <input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text" placeholder="Last name" />
  </div>
  <div id="address">
    <div id="1">
      <input id="mail" name="mail[]" type="text" placeholder="mail" />
      <input id="type" name="type[]" type="text" placeholder="type" />
      <input id="comment" name="comment[]" type="text" placeholder="comment" />
      <a href="#" class="removeclass" style="display:none;">&times;</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <input id="add_address" type="button" value="Ajouter" />
  <input type="submit" value="Create PDF" />
</form>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, or what the issue is. You seem to have an undefined `name` variable in your code example, though

Comment: name is undefined. div has no placeholder , id is unused

Comment: Extract the cloned element to a variable and remove the value.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Please note that the bottom part of this answer is a deprecated one. I realised that most of OP's code was correct and did a too big work-around, which I've corrected straight below.

To make your code work as intended just replace it with following. What I've done is replacing the `.attr(placeholder)` with `.attr(id)` and added a line to remove the values of the new (cloned) element.

```js
$('#add_address').click(function(event) {
  var lastDiv = $('#address > div').last();
  var id = parseInt(lastDiv.attr("id")) + 1;
  (lastDiv.clone(true).attr("id", id)).insertAfter(lastDiv).find(".removeclass").show();
 $("#address div:last-of-type input").val("");
  return false;
});

$('body').on('click', '.removeclass', function(event) {
  $(this).parent().remove();
  return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="test5.php" method="post">
  <div style="margin-bottom:5px;">
    <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="First name" />
    <input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text" placeholder="Last name" />
  </div>
  <div id="address">
    <div id="1">
      <input id="mail" name="mail[]" type="text" placeholder="mail" />
      <input id="type" name="type[]" type="text" placeholder="type" />
      <input id="comment" name="comment[]" type="text" placeholder="comment" />
      <a href="#" class="removeclass" style="display:none;">&times;</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <input id="add_address" type="button" value="Ajouter" />
  <input type="submit" value="Create PDF" />
</form>
```

---

**OLD ANSWER BELOW (unnecessary)**

Here's a possible solution: I've redone the "ID" variable so that the id of the succeeding div's is increased by 1 for each click (1+1 = 2 for div number 2).

Further I simply clone the element as per your code, and afterwards i reset the value to being empty. Hope this is what you wanted.

```js
 $('#add_address').click(function(event) {
        var lastDiv = $('#address div:last-of-type');
        var id = parseInt(lastDiv.attr("id"), 10)+1;
        (lastDiv.clone(true).attr("id", id)).insertAfter(lastDiv).find(".removeclass").show();
        $("#address div:last-of-type input").val("");
        return false;
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.removeclass', function(event) {
        $(this).parent().remove();
        return false;
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="test5.php" method="post">
    <div style ="margin-bottom:5px;">
      <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="First name" />
      <input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text" placeholder="Last name" />
    </div>
    <div id="address">
        <div id="1" >
            <input id="mail" name="mail[]" type="text" placeholder="mail" />
            <input id="type" name ="type[]" type="text" placeholder="type"/>
            <input id="comment" name="comment[]"  type="text" placeholder="comment" />
            <a href="#" class="removeclass" style="display:none;">&times;</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input id="add_address" type="button" value="Add address" />
    <input type="submit" value="Create PDF" />
    </form>
```

Comment: I am very confused, if there is an error in the code I posted. But the code below is suitable for what I wanted to do. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Tony92 I've just upated the answer as I realised there were too many unnecessary changes in the first one. The only "error" you had was that you had an unused variable called `name` and you didn't use the variable `id` anywhere - and then of course that you didn´t clear the cloned input's :)